# MongoDB/mongoose some dates as EDT and others as EST

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When getting some records, I'm seeing that some dates are showing as `GMT-0400 (EDT)` and others are `GMT-0500 (EST)`.

Dates are being added in mongoose simply by using `Date.now` in the schema.

Any ideas what could cause the offsets to be different?

Edit: Here's an example:

Stored as: `ISODate("2015-10-30T15:36:47.287Z")` Returned as: `Fri Oct 30 2015 11:36:47 GMT-0400 (EDT)` using find() with Mongoose

Stored as: `ISODate("2015-11-07T14:44:47.956Z")` Returned as: `Sat Nov 07 2015 09:44:47 GMT-0500 (EST)`  using find() with Mongoose

Comment: Thats odd... I thought Mongo normalizes all dates to UTC?

Comment: Yeah.. so seems to have to do with daylight savings time and JavaScript auto adjusting the dates based on this.  But, I'd like to ignore that so I can query on the same offset.  I updated with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the default string representation of the underlying UTC timestamp, showing the timestamp in the local time zone that was in effect at the time.

In 2015, daylight saving time ended at 2:00 AM on Nov 1, so that's why the first one is shown in EDT and the second one is shown in EST.

Any queries you do are always performed using UTC time.